# Specifying Multiple Languages in an iTunes Connect Application Loader file

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've started playing with the "load batch" capabilities of the iTunes Connect Application Loader, but am not sure from the documentation how to include multiple languages?  It appears that I need to add 2 columns for each new language (Displayed Name/Description), but I'm unclear on what the column header needs to be.  Here's the apple documentation:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Column Name: Description @@language@@

A user-visible description (from
10 to 255 characters) where
@@language@@ is a supported
localized language. You can add
a new column for each localized
language description.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 hours of hard googling, I have not found any answer on this question.

But after one more hour of attempts to guess it, i found that you should just create two columns for each language and named them like "Display Name English" or "Display Name Russian" for example.

UPD: forgot to say, i prepare my InApp tables in Excel